# Highlight text in a RichTextBox Control

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox, highlight

I am trying to highlight multiple lines of specific text in a RichTextBox.
Here is my code for highlighting text:

```
public void HighlightMistakes(RichTextBox richTextBox)
{
    string[] phrases =  { "Drivers Do Not Match", "Current Does Not Match", "No Drivers Found" };      
    foreach (var phrase in phrases)
    {
        int startIndex = 0;
        while (startIndex <= richTextBox.TextLength)
        {
            int phraseStartIndex = richTextBox.Find(phrase, startIndex, RichTextBoxFinds.None);
            if (phraseStartIndex != -1)
            {
                richTextBox.SelectionStart = phraseStartIndex;
                richTextBox.SelectionLength = phrase.Length;
                richTextBox.SelectionBackColor = Color.Yellow;
            }
            else break;
            startIndex += phraseStartIndex + phrase.Length;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is how I add text to RTB and call function above:

```
foreach (var a in resultList)
{
    richTextBox1.AppendText("\n"+a + "\n");
    HighlightMistakes(richTextBox1);
}
```

However, `HighlightMistakes` doesn't work the way I would like it to. The idea is to highlight all string values specified in `phrases` array and that doesn't happen every time.

Examples:

[image]

[image]

I am not sure why some of the lines are skipped and some of them are not.

Comment: Did you try the [debugger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx), your very best friend in the world of coding.

Comment: Consider: you have `SelectionStart = phraseStartIndex` - that means `phraseStartIndex` includes the distance from the beginning of the text, and already has the `startIndex` value accounted for. Then you add `phraseStartIndex` to `startIndex`, which means you set `startIndex` to `startIndex+startIndex+phraseOffset+phrase.Length` so you skip over text. Don't add, set `startIndex = phraseStartIndex+phrase.Length`

Comment: @NetMage, thanks for suggestion but if I do that, the program freezes and application is in break mode :(

Comment: @NetMage however, when I remove ```phraseStartIndex``` from equation, repeated lines are not skipped anymore. Thank for the hint. 
Now I have ```startIndex += phrase.Length```

Comment: I don't think that is correct - it is probably marking phrases multiple times. Are you sure you tried `startIndex = phraseStartIndex + phrase.Length;`? My test program works fine when I do that with your samples.

Comment: @NetMage yes, that is indeed weird and I tried your suggestion first but it didn't work in my case. Does ```startIndex += phrase.Length``` work for you?

Comment: You only need to call `HighlightMistakes(richTextBox1);` once, AFTER the `for` loop.

Comment: @dito Yes, it works, but a test where I switched colors every find showed that it was highlighting the same phrase multiple times.

Comment: BTW, after running some tests and discussing with Microsoft, the `Find` method sets the selection when it finds a match, so you do not need to set `SelectionStart` or `SelectionLength`, that is done by `Find`.

Answer (score 1):

If you have nothing against a simple Regex method, you can use [Regex.Matches](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.matches) to match your list of phrases against the text of your RichTextBox.
Each [Match](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.match) in the collection of Matches contains both the [Index](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.capture.index) (the position inside the text) where the match is found and its [Length](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.capture.length), so you can simply call [.Select(Index, Length)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.select) to select a phrase and highlight it.
The pattern used is the string resulting from joining the phrases to match with a Pipe (`|`).
Each phrase is passed to [Regex.Escape()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape), since the text may contain metacharacters.

If you want to considere the case, remove `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase`.

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

string[] phrases = { "Drivers Do Not Match",
                     "Current Does Not Match",
                     "No Drivers Found" };
HighlightMistakes(richTextBox1, phrases);

private void HighlightMistakes(RichTextBox rtb, string[] phrases)
{
    ClearMistakes(rtb);
    string pattern = string.Join("|", phrases.Select(phr => Regex.Escape(phr)));

    var matches = Regex.Matches(rtb.Text, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    foreach (Match m in matches) {
        rtb.Select(m.Index, m.Length);
        rtb.SelectionBackColor = Color.Yellow;
    }
}

private void ClearMistakes(RichTextBox rtb)
{
    int selStart = rtb.SelectionStart;
    rtb.SelectAll();
    rtb.SelectionBackColor = rtb.BackColor;
    rtb.SelectionStart = selStart;
    rtb.SelectionLength = 0;
}
```